# Как синхронизировать выполнение процедуры в разных заданиях (сессиях)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть такая процедура:

```
create or replace procedure myproc is
    n number;   
begin
    -- Query A
    select count(*) into n from sometable where Col1 = 0;
    if n = 0 then 
        insert into sometable values (0, 'some data');
    else        
        update sometable set Col2 = 'some other data' where Col1 = 0;
    end if;
    commit;
end;
```

Запускаю её в задании, то есть она выполняется параллельно в различных сессиях:

```
declare
    Jobname varchar2 (32);
    JobAction varchar2 (128) := 'begin myproc; end;';                                                               
begin
    for i in 1..10      
    loop
        Jobname := dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name ('JobName');            
        dbms_scheduler.create_job (job_name=>Jobname, job_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK', job_action=>JobAction, enabled => true);        
    end loop;
end;
```

Хочу добиться, чтобы вставить только одну строку в таблице `SomeTable`, а все остальные задания будут обновлять эту же строку. Это работает, но иногда замечаю, что когда все задания завершены, то создается несколько строк вместо одной.

Я понял, что всякий раз, когда выполняется запрос `Query A`, из-за блокировок строк, он будет видеть только те строки таблицы, которые были зафиксированы до начала запроса. Следовательно, другие задания не видят изменения.

Есть ли, несмотря на выше изложенное, какое-то решение?

---

В .Net существует концепция `Monitor.Enter`* и `Monitor.Exit`, которая заставляет все остальные потоки ждать, пока ресурс не будет отпущен.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to synchronize threads in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63114257) от участника [@Thomas Carlton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2635209/thomas-carlton)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63114257

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно воспользоваться [DBMS_LOCK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOCK.html#GUID-ABF571D1-443D-4528-BDD2-50768B4D1898). Измените процедуру как-то так:

```
create or replace procedure MyProc is
    n number;   
    h varchar2(200);
    r number;
begin
    dbms_lock.allocate_unique ('MyLock', h);
    --Query A
    r := dbms_lock.request (h, dbms_lock.x_mode); 
    select count(*) into n from SomeTable where Col1 = 0;
    if n = 0 then 
        insert into SomeTable (Col1, Col2) values (0, 'some data');
    else        
        update SomeTable set Col2 = 'some other data' where Col1 = 0;
    end if;
    commit;
    if dbms_lock.release (h) != 0 then null;
        /* do someting with error */ 
    end if;    
end;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63114796) от участника [@hol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/382009/hol)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Если возможно сделать колонку `Col1` уникальной, то задача упростится:

```
alter table sometable modify (Col1 number unique)
/
```

Так при первой вставке будет заблокирована только одна запись. Если же первая вставка уже зафиксирована, то последующие должны быть игнорированны. Процедура будет выглядит так:

```
create or replace procedure MyProc (name varchar2) is
begin
    insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index (SomeTable (Col1)) */ 
        into SomeTable values (0, 'creator:'||name);
    if sql%rowcount = 0 then          
        update SomeTable set Col2=Col2||'; changer:'||name
        where Col1 = 0;
    end if;     
end;
/
```

После выполнения 10 заданий, получим ожидаемый результат:

```
      COL1 COL2                                                        
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         0 creator:MYJOB4370; changer:MYJOB4388; changer:MYJOB4372;    
           changer:MYJOB4374; changer:MYJOB4380; changer:MYJOB4376;    
           changer:MYJOB4378; changer:MYJOB4382; changer:MYJOB4384;    
           changer:MYJOB4386
```